# Is it possible to link properties between entities in orient db?

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

If I have a property `name` in my class `Project`, is it possible to link that property to the property `project_name` in my class `User`?

I know that I can link a record to another record with a link, but I would like something similar between properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible since properties do not have an identity (physical position) like records, they are only values inside of records.